# Android Reading Assets depending on selected Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement, bufferedreader

I'm developing an app which consists on different tests and for each test (activity) it is needes to      read a different txt file. I know doing this but changing it manually. How could be possible to read the proper txt when an specific activity is running. For example for activity 1 I need to read 1.txt and so on.
Here is the code where i read the txts.

```
String questionFile = "";
questionFile = "1.txt";
questionCount = 20;

Log.i("Question", questionFile + ": " + questionCount);
try {
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(questionFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Skips lines
    for (i = 0; i< questionNumber; i++) {
        reader.readLine();
    }
    question = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to put current code inside separate class and create a method for reading file from Assets depend on Activity currently running as:

```
public class GetFileAssets {
Context context;

public GetFileAssets(Context context){
 this.context=context;
 }

public String readFilefromAssets(String str_file_id){
  String questionFile = "";
  questionFile = str_file_id;
  questionCount = 20;

  //... your code here

  return question;
 }

}
```

and now  pass file  accoding to Activity .like from Actiivty 1:

```
GetFileAssets obj=new GetFileAssets(Activity1.this);
String str=obj.readFilefromAssets("1.txt");
```

same from Activity 2 :

```
GetFileAssets obj=new GetFileAssets(Activity2.this);
String str=obj.readFilefromAssets("2.txt");
```